# Ubuntu - install (Jenkins) Docker containers fails due to creating mount source path: mkdir read-only errors

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, docker-compose

I want to install Jenkins via Docker in an Ubuntu virtual machine (Oracle VM Virtualbox).

When starting 'docker-compose up' I get the following errors:

> ERROR: for dockercompose_postgres_1  Cannot start service postgres:
>   error while creating mount source path '/var/postgres-data': mkdir
>   /var/postgres-data: read-Starting dockercompose_jenkins_1 ... error
>
> ERROR: for dockercompose_jenkins_1  Cannot start service jenkins:
>   error while creating mount source path '/var/jenkins_home': mkdir
>   /var/jenkins_home: read-only file system
>
> ERROR: for jenkins  Cannot start service jenkins: error while creating
>   mount source path '/var/jenkins_home': mkdir /var/jenkins_home:
>   read-only file system
>
> ERROR: for postgres  Cannot start service postgres: error while
>   creating mount source path '/var/postgres-data': mkdir
>   /var/postgres-data: read-only file system ERROR: Encountered errors
>   while bringing up the project.

The context:

- I am logged in as 'osboxes.org' (same name as the Ubuntu image provider).
- Docker-compose is started as 'sudo docker-compose up'.
- The permissions of the folder '/var' is drwxrwxrwx  14 root root  4096 Sep  9 08:48 var
- At first the /var/progres-data and /var/jenkins_home are not existing. The issue is there.
- After creating both folders / directories with 777 permission, the same issue is there.
- The Ubuntu VM is an Osboxes.org Ubuntu virtual machine in Oracle VM Virtualbox on Windows.
- Suggested was a 'sudo mount -o remount,rw /'. No changes.
- Suggested was a 'sudo mount -o remount,rw /var', then I get this warning: mount: /var: mount point not mounted or bad option.

Part of the docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '2'
  services:   jenkins:
    image: jenkins:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    networks:
      - jenkins
    volumes:
      - /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock   
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    networks:
      - jenkins
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: sonar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonarpasswd
    volumes:
      - /var/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      ETC ETC ETC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested was that (after installing Ubuntu VM and starting it) that by typing just 'docker' you get some advice on installing Docker.

Apparently, this is incorrect. There is an correct procedure for installing Docker on Ubuntu!

Please refer to this correct [Ubuntu Docker installation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1). It will help you installing the newest/right version of Docker on Ubuntu. This prevents you getting nasty errors like the ones in the above question.